# How to upload video with Title & description to Firebase using flutter?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

```
 Future uploadtoServer () async{
print(videoFile);
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child('video.mp4');
StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(videoFile, StorageMetadata(contentType: 'video.mp4'));
StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot=await uploadTask.onComplete;
Uri downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete).uploadSessionUri;
final String Url = downloadUrl.toString();
print(Url);

setState(() {
  print(taskSnapshot);

});

return print(_uploadedFileURL);
```

}

[image: Here is a View of My Firebase Storage, also here type showing image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only save your videoLink, description, and title to the **Firestore** database after uploading the video to the Firebase storage.

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore